# converting recursive function from python to scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to convert this recursive function from python code to scala. In python:

```
    def func(x,y,z):
        if x >= y:
            return 0.0
        if y>= 12:
            return 1.0/6**z
        
        probability = 0.0
        
        for val in [1,2,3,4]:
            probability += func(x,y+val,z+1)        
        for val in [5,6]:
            probability += func(x+val,y,z+1)

        return probability

    print(func(1,7,0))
```

In scala, my the code became

```
object Prob extends App {

  println(func(1, 7, 0))

  def func(y: Int, x: Int, z: Int): Double = { 
    if (x>= y) {
      return 0.0;
    }   
    if (y>= 12) {
      return scala.math.pow(1.0/6,z);
    }
      
    var probability : Double = 0.0;
      
    for (i <- 1 to 4) {
        probability += func(x,y+i,z+1);
    }
    for (i <- 5 to 6) {
        probability += func(x+i,y,z+1);
    }
    return probability;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, while the python code returns the correct value of 0.6, the scala code returns 0.0.

Where's the error in the scala code?

Answer (score 4):

You swapped the order of parameters:

```py
def func(hunter,goose,num):
```

```scala
def func(goose: Int, hunter: Int, num: Int): Double = {
```

Since you call `func(1, 7, 0)`, in scala you immediately hit the `hunter >= goose` case, which returns `0`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an equivalent and more idiomatic implementation, which takes advantages of the functional capabilities instead of just being an imperative copy & paste of the original code.

```scala
def func(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): Double =
  if (x >= y)
    0.0d
  else if (y >= 12)
    math.pow(1.0d / 6, z)
  else
    (1 to 6).foldLeft(0.0d) {
      case (probability, i) =>
        val r =
          if (i <= 4) func(x, y + i, z + 1)
          else func(x + i, y, z + 1)
      
        probability + r
    }
```

Changes I made:

- I removed `return` since it is not needed and [not recommended](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html), by taking advantage of the fact that `if` is an **expression** and not a **statement**.
- I removed unnecessary mutability by taking advantage of **higher-order functions** provided by the standard library.
- Style changes like removing `;` *(which is common on most, if not all, Scala programs)* and removing some braces *(which is more of my personal taste)*.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/86suFXvBR7qjF8LiYKELTg/11)*.

Comment: May I ask why you used `case`? Is it a stylistic thing? (because I thought that desugared to creating and destructuring a tuple)

Comment: @user yeah it shouldn't be needed because `foldLeft` expects a function of two arguments, I am  just used to it.

Comment: Oh ok. A `map` and a `sum` might also work, perhaps with a `view`, although it doesn't match the OP's code that much.

Comment: @user yeah I also thought about that, but introducing views or iterators seemed that too much IMHO.